# Vertica Parquet format

Tags: hdfs, vertica, parquet

I use following Vertica version "Vertica Analytic Database v7.1.1-0" and I try to copy data from Parquet format file to table using following query:

```
COPY temp.sessions_parquet FROM '/dbadmin/vertica-import/parquet/*' ON ANY NODE PARQUET;
```

I've created table with following DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE temp.sessions_parquet (c0 VARCHAR, c1 VARCHAR, c2 VARCHAR, c3 VARCHAR, c4 VARCHAR, c5 VARCHAR, c6 VARCHAR, c7 VARCHAR, c8 VARCHAR, c9 VARCHAR, c10 VARCHAR, c11 VARCHAR, c12 VARCHAR, c13 VARCHAR, c14 VARCHAR, c15 VARCHAR, c16 VARCHAR, c17 VARCHAR, c18 VARCHAR, c19 VARCHAR, c20 VARCHAR, c21 VARCHAR, c22 VARCHAR, c23 VARCHAR, c24 VARCHAR, c25 VARCHAR, c26 VARCHAR, c27 VARCHAR, c28 VARCHAR, c29 VARCHAR, c30 VARCHAR, c31 VARCHAR, c32 VARCHAR, c33 VARCHAR, c34 VARCHAR, c35 VARCHAR, c36 VARCHAR, c37 VARCHAR, c38 VARCHAR, c39 VARCHAR, c40 VARCHAR, c41 VARCHAR, c42 VARCHAR, c43 VARCHAR, c44 VARCHAR, c45 VARCHAR, c46 VARCHAR, c47 VARCHAR, c48 VARCHAR, c49 VARCHAR, c50 VARCHAR, c51 VARCHAR, c52 VARCHAR, c53 VARCHAR, c54 VARCHAR, c55 VARCHAR, c56 VARCHAR, c57 VARCHAR);
```

Parquet format file is on Vertica node already in following location:

```
/dbadmin/vertica-import/parquet/part-r-00000.snappy.parquet
```

When I try to execute following command:

```
COPY temp.sessions_parquet FROM '/dbadmin/vertica-import/parquet/*' ON ANY NODE PARQUET;
```

I am getting following error:

> An error occurred when executing the SQL command: COPY
>   temp.sessions_parquet FROM '/dbadmin/vertica-import/parquet/*' ON ANY
>   NODE PARQUET
>
> [Vertica]VJDBC ERROR: Syntax error at or near "PARQUET" [SQL
>   State=42601, DB Errorcode=4856] 1 statement failed.

Could you please help and tell how can I import data?

Comment: I guess you need to upgrade to version 7.2 at least

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading from Parquet files was [first supported in version 7.2.3](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.2.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/NewFeatures/7.2/7.2.3/HadoopParquet.htm).  It looks like you've found the syntax from that version, but you're using it with an old version.

Here is the [documentation of this feature from 7.2.3](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.2.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/HadoopIntegrationGuide/NativeFormats/ReadingNativeFormats.htm).  Note, by the way, that it doesn't support complex types, which is still true in 8.0.x.